# When to use jpa over hibernate native library and is it mandatory?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

JPA support has been included in Hibernate in version 3.4.0 GA. But before that hibernate native library was used for object  persisting . I have also used hibernate in a project without using JPA API. I have a question that what is the real life scenario in which we use JPA and not the hibernate native API. And also is it mandatory to use JPA in hibernate?

Comment: Yet another opinion-based question that the FAQ says are not to be posted on this site.

Comment: This question is not at all opinion based. It needs expertise to answer the question and it needs expertise in the subject.

Comment: evidently everyone else disagrees with you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA is a standard, Hibernate is not. By sticking to the standard you have the power to use any vendor that satisfies it, not just Hibernate (e.g. EclipseLink, OpenJPA, etc.)

One thing you could do if you're using the standard is chage from one
provider to another and expect that things should work the same in your code. For instance if your current provider had a bug, or stopped existing leaving you without support and unable to evolve or add new features to your APIs.

Following the standard also guarantees your APIs can stay up to date with the latest features added to the specification as it evolves over time.

There could even be political reasons within an organization or project: a commitment to just use standard technologies and APIs.

The standard evolves based on the vision and experience brought to the table by multiple vendors. So the Hibernate team does influences what new features should be added to the specification, but so do other vendors. So you can expect the standard to reflect the collective experience and perspective of the community and not just that of a single vendor.

That being said, the truth is that Hibernate itself offers a much richer set of features than those just required by JPA and Hibernate evolves at a much faster pace. Plus it looks like pretty solid technology. So those could be good reasons to use Hibernate directly to take more advantage of their technology and use it to their full potential.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So that means in any project that needs persisting technology  we can still use hibernate native library only. I cases besides project commitment that uses standard technology we can use JPA with an advantage  that if needed in future we can replace one JPA provide with any better JPA provider.                                                                                                             Is there any disadvantages of JPA?

Comment: The only disadvantage of JPA is that you can do a lot more with hibernate native API then with JPA. It is simply because hibernate provides non-standard features and JPA is a common API that every other implementation has to support - it is a common denominator. But I would prefer to use JPA where possible, and resort to hibernate specific features only where necessary - learning and using JPA means that you can leverage the same knowledge in later projects, which don't use hibernate.